# Python Flask unittest can't set headers for GET requests

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest, werkzeug

I am trying to set a Token in my header request for unit test:

```
def setUp(self):
    #app = Flask(__name__)
    self.app = main.application.test_client()

def login(self):
    payload = {"user": "*******", "password": "******"}
    url ='/user/auth'
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    response = self.app.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers) 
    result = json.loads(response.data)
    token = str(result["data"]["Token"])
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json','Token':token}
    return headers


def GetTool(self):
    headers= self.login()
    return self.app.get('/tool/all',headers=headers,follow_redirects=True)
```

But the headers are not set. I know that because I am printing it. See below:

```
@toolAPI.route('/tool/all/', methods=['GET'])
#@authService.authorized
def getAllTools():
   print '*request headers'
   print request.headers
   try:
      ......
```

This is what I get in the logs:

```
8:27:07 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  ######HTTP MODE######
18:27:07 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  *request headers
18:27:07 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Host: localhost
18:27:07 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Content-Length: 0
18:27:07 [MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Content-Type
```

Any suggestions what the issue is?

Comment: is there a way to provide a [mcve] ? I know this is difficult with web stuff but could you do that? (still +1 for the compact question). Maybe by hardcoding the site response in your code so the code can be run offline? BTW where is `app` defined?

Comment: Why do you believe that "the headers are not set", what *exactly* are you observing, and what is the tested code that tries to read this header? From the code it seems just as likely that the receiving /tool/all might expect the token in some slightly different manner than a separate nonstandard HTTP header named "Token".

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i tried to provide details tell me if it helps

Comment: @Peteris i have added coded regarding the header prints + logs

Answer (score 3):

In your test file.

```
class TestYourthing(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = main.app.test_client()
        # get your token from somewhere
        self.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Token': token}

    def test_forbidden_get(self):
        """GET is forbidden for this route."""
        rv = self.client.get('/somewhere', headers=self.headers)
        self.assertEqual(rv.status_code, 404)

    # if you need to update locally the headers for a test

    def test_post_working(self):
        """testing POST for blah"""
        # Adding another header here
        self.headers.update({'X-Blah': 'ping'})
        rv = self.client.post('/somewhere', headers=self.headers)
        self.assertEqual(rv.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could set HTTP headers like this:

```
 client.environ_base['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = 'application/xml'
 response = client.get("/", follow_redirects=True)
```

The client seems to strip the "HTTP_" prefix before executing the request.